# IntelliJ and Glassfish 3.1.2.1

Tags: java, intellij-idea, glassfish

I upgraded IntelliJ from 2019.1 to 2019.2 and now I can't deploy glassfish 3.1.2.1 in the project with JavaEE6 and JavaJDK1.7. The error that I receive in IntelliJ is:

```
[2019-10-31 12:55:16,424] Artifact gbox-deploy:ear: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
[2019-10-31 12:55:16,424] Artifact gbox-mh-deploy:ear: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Detected server admin port: 4848
Detected server http port: 8080
Attempting to start domain1.... Please look at the server log for more details.....
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:9009', transport: 'socket'
```

The glassfish admin has been started but it hasn't deployed my ear files. Finally I have checked the C:\Users\AUser\MyGlassfish\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs but it doesn't have anything.

I attach also the the idea.log found in C:\Users\AUser.Mattes.IntelliJIdea2019.2\system\log

```
2019-10-31 16:14:02,837 [  35697]   INFO - pl.projectlevelman.NewMappings - VCS Root: [hg4idea] - [<Project>] 
2019-10-31 16:14:03,576 [  36436]   INFO -              PerformancePlugin - Performance Plugin is in silent mode 
2019-10-31 16:14:04,238 [  37098]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 455ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2019-10-31 16:14:04,827 [  37687]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: C:/Users/AUser/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar 
2019-10-31 16:14:04,899 [  37759]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". 
2019-10-31 16:14:04,900 [  37760]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation 
2019-10-31 16:14:04,900 [  37760]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details. 
2019-10-31 16:14:05,540 [  38400]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/general/ideOptions.png' with 'AllIcons.General.Settings' 
2019-10-31 16:14:05,545 [  38405]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred 
2019-10-31 16:14:05,545 [  38405]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil (file:/C:/Users/AUser/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.2.4/lib/protobuf-java-3.5.1.jar) to field java.nio.Buffer.address 
2019-10-31 16:14:05,545 [  38405]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil 
2019-10-31 16:14:05,545 [  38405]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations 
2019-10-31 16:14:05,545 [  38405]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release 
2019-10-31 16:14:05,565 [  38425]   INFO - ge.ExternalProjectsDataStorage - Load external projects data in 0 millis (read time: 0) 
2019-10-31 16:14:05,591 [  38451]   INFO - j.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProvider - 199 ms spent to cache options in project 
2019-10-31 16:14:05,625 [  38485]   WARN - com.intellij.util.xmlb.Binding - no accessors for class org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.highlighter.KotlinDefaultHighlightingSettingsProvider 
2019-10-31 16:14:05,830 [  38690]   WARN - com.intellij.util.xmlb.Binding - no accessors for class com.intellij.plugins.jboss.arquillian.configuration.persistent.ArquillianLibraryState 
2019-10-31 16:14:05,854 [  38714]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Post-startup activities under progress took 2089ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: 1/2 sluggish 
2019-10-31 16:14:06,007 [  38867]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - C:/Users/AUser/MyProjects/myproject/maven-project/.idea case-sensitivity: expected=false actual=false 
2019-10-31 16:14:06,169 [  39029]   INFO - Json.PackageJsonUpdateNotifier - processPackageJsonFiles [] 
2019-10-31 16:14:07,230 [  40090]   INFO - pl.projectlevelman.NewMappings - Mapped Roots: 1 
2019-10-31 16:14:07,696 [  40556]   INFO - ea.execution.HgCommandExecutor - hg.exe branches  
2019-10-31 16:14:07,811 [  40671]   INFO - tor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl - Project opening took 5005 ms 
2019-10-31 16:14:08,323 [  41183]   INFO - ea.execution.HgCommandExecutor - hg.exe log --template {rev}\u0017{node}\u0017{p1rev}:{p1node} {p2rev}:{p2node}\u0017{date|hgdate}\u0017{author}\u0017\u0003 
2019-10-31 16:14:09,961 [  42821]   INFO - ea.execution.HgCommandExecutor - hg.exe log --template {rev}\u0017{node}\u0017{p1rev}:{p1node} {p2rev}:{p2node}\u0017{date|hgdate}\u0017{author}\u0017{desc}\u0017\u0003 --limit 1000 
2019-10-31 16:14:12,365 [  45225]   INFO - ea.execution.HgCommandExecutor - hg.exe incoming  
2019-10-31 16:14:13,455 [  46315]   INFO - ea.execution.HgCommandExecutor - hg.exe outgoing  
2019-10-31 16:14:13,868 [  46728]   INFO - s.CompilerReferenceServiceBase - backward reference index reader is opened 
2019-10-31 16:14:13,992 [  46852]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appMavenVersion took 36 ms, UISettings took 14 ms 
2019-10-31 16:14:14,226 [  47086]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: C:/Users/AUser/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar 
2019-10-31 16:14:14,346 [  47206]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". 
2019-10-31 16:14:14,347 [  47207]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation 
2019-10-31 16:14:14,347 [  47207]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details. 
2019-10-31 16:14:14,713 [  47573]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project 'C:\Users\AUser\MyProjects\mobileapp' mobileappRunManager took 13 ms 
2019-10-31 16:14:15,045 [  47905]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project 'C:\Users\AUser\MyProjects\myproject\maven-project' maven-projectArtifactManager took 30 ms, RunManager took 13 ms, libraryTable took 47 ms 
2019-10-31 16:14:15,052 [  47912]   INFO - mponents.impl.stores.StoreUtil - saveProjectsAndApp took 1946 ms 
2019-10-31 16:14:16,224 [  49084]   INFO - ea.execution.HgCommandExecutor - hg.exe log --template {rev}\u0017{node}\u0017{p1rev}:{p1node} {p2rev}:{p2node}\u0017{date|hgdate}\u0017{author}\u0017\u0003 
2019-10-31 16:14:17,317 [  50177]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred 
2019-10-31 16:14:17,317 [  50177]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil (file:/C:/Users/AUser/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.2.4/lib/protobuf-java-3.5.1.jar) to field java.nio.Buffer.address 
2019-10-31 16:14:17,317 [  50177]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil 
2019-10-31 16:14:17,317 [  50177]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations 
2019-10-31 16:14:17,317 [  50177]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release 
2019-10-31 16:14:18,014 [  50874]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 13775ms; general responsiveness: 0/13 sluggish, 1/13 very slow; EDT responsiveness: 3/13 sluggish, 2/13 very slow 
2019-10-31 16:14:18,014 [  50874]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update started: 26 files to update 
2019-10-31 16:14:18,291 [  51151]   INFO - ings.impl.UpdateCheckerService - channel: release 
2019-10-31 16:14:18,902 [  51762]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Unindexed files update took 888ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2019-10-31 16:14:18,906 [  51766]   INFO - g.FileBasedIndexProjectHandler - Reindexing refreshed files: 0 to update, calculated in 2ms 
2019-10-31 16:14:18,926 [  51786]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === StatusBar.start create === 
2019-10-31 16:14:19,248 [  52108]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - Some post-startup activities freeze UI for noticeable time. Please consider making them DumbAware to run them in background under modal progress, or just making them faster to speed up project opening. 
2019-10-31 16:14:21,084 [  53944]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/general/ideOptions.png' with 'AllIcons.General.Settings' 
2019-10-31 16:14:29,566 [  62426]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: C:/Users/AUser/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar 
2019-10-31 16:14:29,614 [  62474]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". 
2019-10-31 16:14:29,614 [  62474]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation 
2019-10-31 16:14:29,614 [  62474]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details. 
2019-10-31 16:14:30,064 [  62924]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred 
2019-10-31 16:14:30,064 [  62924]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil (file:/C:/Users/AUser/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.2.4/lib/protobuf-java-3.5.1.jar) to field java.nio.Buffer.address 
2019-10-31 16:14:30,064 [  62924]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil 
2019-10-31 16:14:30,064 [  62924]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations 
2019-10-31 16:14:30,064 [  62924]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release 
2019-10-31 16:14:31,407 [  64267]   INFO - s.CompilerReferenceServiceBase - backward reference index reader is opened 
2019-10-31 16:14:31,816 [  64676]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: C:/Users/AUser/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar 
2019-10-31 16:14:31,886 [  64746]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". 
2019-10-31 16:14:31,886 [  64746]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation 
2019-10-31 16:14:31,886 [  64746]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details. 
2019-10-31 16:14:32,823 [  65683]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred 
2019-10-31 16:14:32,823 [  65683]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil (file:/C:/Users/AUser/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.2.4/lib/protobuf-java-3.5.1.jar) to field java.nio.Buffer.address 
2019-10-31 16:14:32,823 [  65683]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil 
2019-10-31 16:14:32,823 [  65683]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations 
2019-10-31 16:14:32,823 [  65683]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release 
2019-10-31 16:14:37,600 [  70460]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project 'C:\Users\AUser\MyProjects\myproject\maven-project' maven-projectlibraryTable took 31 ms 
2019-10-31 16:14:37,601 [  70461]   INFO - mponents.impl.stores.StoreUtil - saveProjectsAndApp took 148 ms 
2019-10-31 16:15:03,355 [  96215]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project 'C:\Users\AUser\MyProjects\myproject\maven-project' maven-projectlibraryTable took 18 ms 
2019-10-31 16:15:03,355 [  96215]   INFO - mponents.impl.stores.StoreUtil - saveProjectsAndApp took 108 ms 
2019-10-31 16:15:08,999 [ 101859]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project 'C:\Users\AUser\MyProjects\myproject\maven-project' maven-projectlibraryTable took 20 ms 
2019-10-31 16:15:09,045 [ 101905]   INFO - ij.compiler.impl.CompileDriver - COMPILATION STARTED (BUILD PROCESS) 
2019-10-31 16:15:09,127 [ 101987]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - Using preloaded build process to compile C:\Users\AUser\MyProjects\myproject\maven-project 
2019-10-31 16:15:09,257 [ 102117]   INFO - lij.compiler.impl.CompilerUtil -     COMPILATION FINISHED (BUILD PROCESS); Errors: 0; warnings: 0 took 219 ms: 0 min 0sec 
2019-10-31 16:15:09,269 [ 102129]   INFO - s.CompilerReferenceServiceBase - backward reference index reader is opened 
2019-10-31 16:15:09,332 [ 102192]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project 'C:\Users\AUser\MyProjects\myproject\maven-project' maven-projectlibraryTable took 22 ms 
2019-10-31 16:15:09,403 [ 102263]   INFO - ij.compiler.impl.CompileDriver - COMPILATION STARTED (BUILD PROCESS) 
2019-10-31 16:15:09,414 [ 102274]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - Using preloaded build process to compile C:\Users\AUser\MyProjects\myproject\maven-project 
2019-10-31 16:15:09,618 [ 102478]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: C:/Users/AUser/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar 
2019-10-31 16:15:09,671 [ 102531]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". 
2019-10-31 16:15:09,671 [ 102531]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation 
2019-10-31 16:15:09,671 [ 102531]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details. 
2019-10-31 16:15:11,075 [ 103935]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred 
2019-10-31 16:15:11,075 [ 103935]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil (file:/C:/Users/AUser/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.2.4/lib/protobuf-java-3.5.1.jar) to field java.nio.Buffer.address 
2019-10-31 16:15:11,075 [ 103935]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil 
2019-10-31 16:15:11,075 [ 103935]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations 
2019-10-31 16:15:11,075 [ 103935]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release 
2019-10-31 16:15:14,357 [ 107217]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project 'C:\Users\AUser\MyProjects\myproject\maven-project' maven-projectlibraryTable took 21 ms 
2019-10-31 16:15:53,712 [ 146572]   INFO - lij.compiler.impl.CompilerUtil -     COMPILATION FINISHED (BUILD PROCESS); Errors: 0; warnings: 0 took 44310 ms: 0 min 44sec 
2019-10-31 16:15:53,727 [ 146587]   INFO - s.CompilerReferenceServiceBase - backward reference index reader is opened 
2019-10-31 16:15:54,200 [ 147060]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: C:/Users/AUser/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar 
2019-10-31 16:15:54,285 [ 147145]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". 
2019-10-31 16:15:54,285 [ 147145]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation 
2019-10-31 16:15:54,285 [ 147145]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details. 
2019-10-31 16:15:55,894 [ 148754]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred 
2019-10-31 16:15:55,894 [ 148754]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil (file:/C:/Users/AUser/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.2.4/lib/protobuf-java-3.5.1.jar) to field java.nio.Buffer.address 
2019-10-31 16:15:55,894 [ 148754]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil 
2019-10-31 16:15:55,894 [ 148754]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations 
2019-10-31 16:15:55,894 [ 148754]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release 
2019-10-31 16:15:56,339 [ 149199]   INFO - ij.execution.JavaExecutionUtil - Agent jars were copied to C:\Users\AUser\.IntelliJIdea2019.2\system\captureAgent 
2019-10-31 16:15:56,560 [ 149420]   INFO - ij.execution.JavaExecutionUtil - Agent jars were copied to C:\Users\AUser\.IntelliJIdea2019.2\system\captureAgent 
2019-10-31 16:16:32,693 [ 185553]  ERROR - t.impl.ThreadInvocationHandler - null 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.intellij.remoteServer.agent.impl.ThreadInvocationHandler.lambda$invoke$0(ThreadInvocationHandler.java:53)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.doRun(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:207)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.access$100(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:29)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.lambda$run$0(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:185)
    at com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:208)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:181)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy177.connect(Unknown Source)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.agent.ContextThreadAgentProxyFactory$ContextThreadAgentProxyFactoryDelegate$1$1.invoke(ContextThreadAgentProxyFactory.java:83)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/BASE64Encoder
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:550)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.util.HttpConnectorAddress.getBase64Encoded(HttpConnectorAddress.java:312)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.util.HttpConnectorAddress.getBasicAuthString(HttpConnectorAddress.java:306)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.util.HttpConnectorAddress.setAuthentication(HttpConnectorAddress.java:285)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.util.HttpConnectorAddress.setOptions(HttpConnectorAddress.java:280)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.util.HttpConnectorAddress.openConnection(HttpConnectorAddress.java:264)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.util.HttpConnectorAddress.openConnection(HttpConnectorAddress.java:134)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.glassfish.agent.Glassfish31AgentBase.getConnection(Glassfish31AgentBase.java:40)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.glassfish.agent.Glassfish3AgentBase.invoke(Glassfish3AgentBase.java:142)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.glassfish.agent.Glassfish3AgentBase.doConnect(Glassfish3AgentBase.java:34)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.agent.SimpleAgentBase$1.doJob(SimpleAgentBase.java:24)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.agent.SimpleAgentBase$1.doJob(SimpleAgentBase.java:20)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.agent.SimpleAgentJob.perform(SimpleAgentJob.java:12)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.agent.SimpleAgentBase.connect(SimpleAgentBase.java:33)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.BASE64Encoder
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 43 more
2019-10-31 16:16:32,709 [ 185569]  ERROR - t.impl.ThreadInvocationHandler - IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4  Build #IU-192.7142.36 
2019-10-31 16:16:32,710 [ 185570]  ERROR - t.impl.ThreadInvocationHandler - JDK: 11.0.4; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2019-10-31 16:16:32,710 [ 185570]  ERROR - t.impl.ThreadInvocationHandler - OS: Windows 10 
2019-10-31 16:16:32,712 [ 185572]  ERROR - t.impl.ThreadInvocationHandler - Last Action: JRebel Debug 
2019-10-31 16:16:32,712 [ 185572]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - null 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy177.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.JavaeeAgentAdminServerBase.doConnect(JavaeeAgentAdminServerBase.java:117)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.server.JavaeeServerInstanceImpl.doConnect(JavaeeServerInstanceImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.server.JavaeeServerConnector.checkConnect(JavaeeServerConnector.java:87)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.server.JavaeeServerConnector.isConnected(JavaeeServerConnector.java:106)
    at com.intellij.javaee.run.execution.J2EEProcessHandlerHelper.isConnected(J2EEProcessHandlerHelper.java:256)
    at com.intellij.javaee.run.execution.J2EEProcessHandlerHelper$MyPingAction.ping(J2EEProcessHandlerHelper.java:343)
    at com.intellij.javaee.run.execution.J2EEProcessHandlerHelper$MyPingAction.run(J2EEProcessHandlerHelper.java:308)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:294)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2019-10-31 16:16:32,717 [ 185577]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4  Build #IU-192.7142.36 
2019-10-31 16:16:32,717 [ 185577]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - JDK: 11.0.4; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2019-10-31 16:16:32,717 [ 185577]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - OS: Windows 10 
2019-10-31 16:16:32,719 [ 185579]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Last Action: JRebel Debug 
2019-10-31 16:17:11,859 [ 224719]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project 'C:\Users\AUser\MyProjects\myproject\maven-project' maven-projectlibraryTable took 22 ms 
2019-10-31 16:17:11,867 [ 224727]   INFO - mponents.impl.stores.StoreUtil - saveProjectsAndApp took 220 ms 
2019-10-31 16:17:11,954 [ 224814]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project 'C:\Users\AUser\MyProjects\myproject\maven-project' maven-projectlibraryTable took 18 ms
```

Thanks

Comment: Are there any errors in [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files)? Try re-add the Glassfish server in IDE and re-create Run Configuration from scratch.

Comment: I retried to run the configuration from scratch but with no success. For the log I suppose you mean .IntelliJIdea2019.2/system/log/idea.log

Comment: Looks like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-201756 Please try 1.8 JDK to run GF server. Has it worked with this JDK on 2019.1 version?

Comment: The Project is JDK 1.7, the same is for glassfish. With IntelliJ 2019.1 I had both glassfish and project JDK 1.7 and it worked fine. I tried putting GF in Configurations of glassfish to 1.8, I have the same error plus IntelliJ pops a message saying that the project and glassfish do not have the same JDK version

Comment: I think the error is here: 2019-10-31 16:16:32,710 [ 185570]  ERROR - t.impl.ThreadInvocationHandler - JDK: 11.0.4; VM, It seems that it takes the JDK 11 and not 1.7...not sure

Comment: I downgrad to IntelliJ 2019.1.3 (I had IntelliJ 2019.1) but I still get the same error. I have tried different versions but still the same...So it seems there is something else wrong

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
The problem is that the java environment that Idea runs under was Java 11. I needed to switch this to Java 8.

I followed this article:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under

(for intellij idea v. 2019.3)
The steps in the link say (in very short form):

- Install the Choose Runtime plugin (screenshot).
- Open the runtime plugin and select the java 8 version
- restart idea

Afterwards idea could work with the old glassfish